# SQL/MySQL DELETE all rows EXCEPT 2 of them

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a database table setup like this:

```
   id | code  | group_id | status ---
   ---|-------|---------|------------
    1 | abcd1 | group_1 | available
    2 | abcd2 | group_1 | available
    3 | adsd3 | group_1 | available
    4 | dfgd4 | group_1 | available
    5 | vfcd5 | group_1 | available

    6 | bgcd6 | group_2 | available
    7 | abcd7 | group_2 | available
    8 | ahgf8 | group_2 | available
    9 | dfgd9 | group_2 | available
   10 | qwer6 | group_2 | available
```

In the example above, each `group_id` has 5 total rows (arbitrary for example, total rows will be dynamic and vary), I need to remove every row that matches `available` in `status` ***except for 2 of them*** (which 2 does not matter, as long as there are 2 of them remaining)

Basically every unique `group_id` should only have `2` total rows with `status` of `available`.  I am able to do a simple SQL query to remove all of them, but struggling to come up with a SQL query to remove all ***except for 2*** ... please helppppp :)

Comment: Are the `code` values unique for the table, the group, or non-unique?

Comment: Yes the `code` values are unique, and the `id` is auto_increment primary key

Comment: Do you want to delete rows whose status is not available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `code` is unique, you can use subqueries to keep the "min" and "max"

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE t.status = 'available' 
   AND (t.group_id, t.code) NOT IN (
      SELECT group_id, MAX(code) 
      FROM t 
      WHERE status = 'available' 
      GROUP BY group_id
  )
  AND (t.group_id, t.code) NOT IN (
      SELECT group_id, MIN(code) 
      FROM t 
      WHERE status = 'available' 
      GROUP BY group_id
  )
```

Similarly, with an auto increment id:

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE t.status = 'available' 
   AND t.id NOT IN (
      SELECT MAX(id) FROM t WHERE status = 'available' GROUP BY group_id
      UNION
      SELECT MIN(id) FROM t WHERE status = 'available' GROUP BY group_id
)
```

I reworked the subquery into a UNION instead in this version, but the "AND" format would work just as well too. Also, if "code" was unique across the whole table, the NOT IN could be simplified down to excluding the group_id as well (though it would still be needed in the subqueries' GROUP BY clauses).

---

Edit: MySQL doesn't like subqueries referencing tables being UPDATEd/DELETEd in the WHERE of the query doing the UPDATE/DELETE; in those cases, you can usually double-wrap the subquery to give it an alias, causing MySQL to treat it as a temporary table (behind the scenes).

```
DELETE FROM t
WHERE t.status = 'available' 
   AND t.id NOT IN ( 
      SELECT * FROM (
         SELECT MAX(id) FROM t WHERE status = 'available' GROUP BY group_id
         UNION
         SELECT MIN(id) FROM t WHERE status = 'available' GROUP BY group_id
      ) AS a
)
```

Another alternative, I don't recall if MySQL complains as much about joins in DELETE/UPDATE....

```
DELETE t
FROM t
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT MIN(id) AS minId, MAX(id) AS maxId, 1 AS keep_flag 
   FROM t 
   WHERE status = 'available' 
   GROUP BY group_id
) AS tKeep ON t.id IN (tKeep.minId, tKeep.maxId)
WHERE t.status = 'available' 
    AND tKeep.keep_flag IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, I would also need a WHERE query on the `status` to make sure to only remove rows where the `status = "available"`, what would be the correct spot to put that in this code?

Comment: Opps, I forgot about that. I added the conditions in the appropriate spot now. You want it in both places because: the outer query's WHERE condition preserves everything <> 'available', and the subqueries need it to get the first and last 'available'. Omitting it from the subqueries could preserve less than desired if the first or last were not 'available'.

Comment: Thanks, seems there's an error "You can't specify target table t for update in FROM clause" -- appears to be something similar to this https://www.davidtan.org/mysql-error-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause-solution/

Comment: Using a `SELECT *` does work, but when trying to use the `DELETE` it throws that error

Comment: I just edited with how I think the subquery needs wrapped, is that how you tried `SELECT *`?

Comment: Awesome, the update with UNION for the DELETE issue worked perfectly, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

To keep the min and max ids, I think a `join` is the simplest solution:

```
DELETE t
     FROM t LEFT JOIN
          (SELECT group_id, MIN(id) as min_id, MAX(id) as max_id
           FROM t
           WHERE t.status = 'available' 
           GROUP BY group_id
          ) tt
          ON t.id IN (tt.min_id, tt.max_id)
WHERE t.status = 'available' AND
      tt.group_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the column "`id`" is the PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE KEY, then we could use a correlated subquery to get the second lowest value for a particular `group_id`.

We could then use that to identify rows for `group_id` that have higher values of the "`id`" column.

A query something like this:

```
 SELECT t.`id`
      , t.`group_id` 
   FROM `setup_like_this` t
  WHERE t.`status`  = 'available'
    AND t.`id`
          > ( SELECT s.`id`
                FROM `setup_like_this` s
               WHERE s.`status`   = 'available'
                 AND s.`group_id` = t.`group_id`
               ORDER
                  BY s.`id`
               LIMIT 1,1
            )
```

We test that as a SELECT first, to examine the rows that are returned. When we are satisfied this query is returning the set of rows we want to delete, we can replace `SELECT ... FROM` with `DELETE t.* FROM` to convert it to a `DELETE` statement to remove the rows.

---

Error 1093 encountered converting to DELETE statement.

One workaround is to make the query above into a inline view, and then join to the target table

```
DELETE q.*
  FROM `setup_like_this` q
  JOIN ( -- inline view, query from above returns `id` of rows we want to delete
         SELECT t.`id`
              , t.`group_id` 
           FROM `setup_like_this` t
          WHERE t.`status`  = 'available'
            AND t.`id`
                  > ( SELECT s.`id`
                        FROM `setup_like_this` s
                       WHERE s.`status`   = 'available'
                         AND s.`group_id` = t.`group_id`
                       ORDER
                          BY s.`id`
                       LIMIT 1,1
                    )
       ) r
    ON r.id = q.id
```

Comment: Ahh sorry yeah i meant to set that to `id` as yes that is the auto increment primary key, will give this a try and report back, thanks for quick response

Comment: Which SELECT are you referring to for using DELETE in?  Also, I omitted it for clarity sake, but I do also need to do a WHERE query on the `status` column to make sure to only remove rows that `status = "available"`

Comment: The predicate on `status = 'available'` should be include in both the outer query and the correlated subquery (answer is edited to include that) To convert this to a `DELETE` statement, replace the `SELECT t.id, t.group_id FROM` on the outer query with `DELETE t.* FROM`.

Comment: Thanks for response, same as with https://stackoverflow.com/a/57207456/378506 the error on DELETE, works fine with SELECT but get "You can't specify target table t for update in FROM clause" when try to use DELETE

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, code, group_id, status
from (
  select id, code, group_id, status
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY group_id 
      ORDER BY id DESC) row_num
    ) rownum
  from a
) q
where rownum < 3
```

Comment: You must mention that this would work only in MySql 8.0+